# Replace except for the first occurrence in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file where all the servers are listed as `Dominos_A`.

Is it possible to change the occurrence of `Dominos_A` to `Dominos_B`, `Dominos_C` except the first match?

**FileA:**

```
  ..
  ....
  .....
  Server = Dominos_A.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_A.check
  Server = Dominos_A.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_A.check
```

to

**FileA:**

```
  ..
  ....
  .....
  Server = Dominos_A.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_B.check
  Server = Dominos_C.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_D.check
  ..
```

I tried with `substr`, still i am unable to get the change.

Comment: please post your current code (the stuff with `substr`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your last occurrence does not go beyond `Z` letter, you can

```
perl -i -pe'
  BEGIN{ @r = "A" .. "Z" }
  s|Dominos_\K\w| shift @r |e;
  # for perl 5.8 or older
  # s|(Dominos_)\w| $1 . shift @r |e; 
' FileA
```

Comment: Tx a ton. no the file stops at P. tx again a bunch

Comment: Nice. But the `s/(...).../$1 .../` pattern can be avoided by a lookbehind, e.g `s/Dominos_\K\w/shift @r/e`.

Comment: The increment operator also works with strings: `perl -plwe'BEGIN{ $a = "A" }; s/D_\K\w/$a++/e'` This way will also work past `Z` and go on with `AA`, `AB`, etc.

Comment: @TLP tnx, didn't know that increment is overloaded

Comment: @mpapec It's referred to as "magic" in [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement).

Answer (score 1):

@mpapec..Unfortunately this does not work on my solaris box with perl v5.8.4.

So i have written a slightly different one that works for me.

```
> perl -pe 'BEGIN{@r="A".."Z";$i=0}s/(Dominos_)A/$1$r[$i++]/g' temp
  ..
  ....
  .....
  Server = Dominos_A.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_B.check
  Server = Dominos_C.check
  ..
  .
  Server = Dominos_D.check
>
```